# apache, how to define index page via PT passthrough and preserve query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

we have a virtual host with sub dirs for language.
e.g. /en/home.html

When the user goes to [www.oursite.com](http://www.oursite.com) we want it to show the contents of /en/home.html, NOT to show this: [www.oursite.com/en/home.html](http://www.oursite.com/en/home.html).

And we need it to preserve the query parameters, e.g. [www.oursite.com?affiliate=123](http://www.oursite.com?affiliate=123)

Should still show the contents of /en/home.html, but preserve the params so the page can read them.

Presumably, we can do this:

```
    RewriteRule "^$" "/pt/home.html" [PT]
```

But but this will thrown away the query params.

Presumably we need something like this?

```
    RewriteRule "^$" "/pt/home.html?{$QUERYPARMS}" [PT]
```

Comment: "but this will thrown away the query params" - Is this from your testing? Or just what you think will happen? This shouldn't "throw away the query params". Why are you using the `PT` flag? Unless there is something else going on, you probably shouldn't be using the `PT` flag here. Just the `L` flag.

Comment: PT flag is passthrough. Otherwise it will presumably do a redirect (unless passthrough is the default), and you will get "www.mystite.com/pt/home.html" instead of "www.mystite.com"

Comment: "Otherwise it will presumably do a redirect (unless passthrough is the default)" - No (assuming you mean an "external redirect") and no, passthrough is not the default in a _virtualhost_ context (which is where I assume these directives are being used*). The `PT` flag causes the result of the rewrite to be passed through to the next round of processing as a URL-path (to be reprocessed by the rewrite engine and other modules). This is the default behaviour in a _directory_ context (`<Directory>` or `.htaccess`) but not in a _virtualhost_ (or _server_) context.

Comment: * Where _exactly_ are you (proposing to?) using these directives? I'm assuming directly in the VirtualHost (as you've not stated otherwise and the `PT` flag only really makes sense in a _virtualhost_ context), however, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ `^$` would only match in a _directory_ context (ie. inside a `<Directory>` container) - so it's unclear?

Comment: Interesting!  The rewrite rules are inside a VirtualHost, but not a Directory container, and they seem to work for all our other passthrough and redirects. Its just the initial index page which is proving difficult.