# mod rewrite question: how to match empty path but preserve query params?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

AEM Cloud CMS uses apache (they call it dispatcher), but they dont allow "DirectoryIndex" so you have to do your own rewriting.

We would like to map: "www.mysite.com" to the index page: /uk/home.html with passthrough (so user sees "www.mysite.com" instead of "www.mysite.com/uk/home.html".

However, we also want to preserve parameters.

Something like this:

```
    RewriteRule "^$" "/uk/home.html" [PT]
```

Will work, but presumably only if there are no query params.

Given: "www.mysite.com?hello=world" or Given: "www.mysite.com/?hello=world" or "www.mysite.com/#something"

we want "www.mysite.com?hello=world" to show in the address bar, but the contents page /uk/home.html to be displayed.

Maybe we should be using several rules?

```
    # case: www.mysite.com?xxx
    RewriteRule "^\?.*$" "/uk/home.html?$1" [PT]

    # case: www.mysite.com
    RewriteRule "^$" "/uk/home.html" [PT]

    # case: www.mysite.com/
    RewriteRule "^/$" "/uk/home.html" [PT]

    # case: www.mysite.com/?xxx
    RewriteRule "^/\?.*$" "/uk/home.html?$1" [PT]

    # case: www.mysite.com#xxx
    RewriteRule "^\#.*$" "/uk/home.html#$1" [PT]

    # case: www.mysite.com/#xxx
    RewriteRule "^/\#.*$" "/uk/home.html/#$1" [PT]
    etc.
```

AEM Cloud takes around 2-4 hours to deploy to to test a one line change, so trial and error takes a very long time.

Comment: you can't rewrite based on `#something`, that part happens only in client's browser, it is never sent as part of http request

Comment: This would seem to be a dupe of your earlier question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287304/apache-how-to-define-index-page-via-pt-passthrough-and-preserve-query-string

Comment: Where _exactly_ are these directives to be used? What other directives do you have? "with passthrough" - Your definition of "passthrough" (`PT` flag) would seem to be incorrect. "they dont allow "DirectoryIndex"" - In what way don't they "allow DirectoryIndex"?! (That seems very bizarre, what other things don't they "allow"?) "but presumably only if there are no query params" - Your "assumptions" are incorrect. Query string string parameters are passed through by default, providing you don't explicitly include a query string in the _substitution_.

Comment: DirectoryIndex is sadly not allowed by Adobe. They check for its presence and fail the build if it exists in the config.  I presume its because they put apache in front of Sling, which is not a file system based content repository.